# How do you check if a text field in a GUI contains something?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to check if a user's input into a text field contains certain letters and have it increment a counter if it does.

```
//this is the code for the button
//tfYourName is the name of the text field
//below is what I've tried already
private void btnResultsMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {   
    if (tfYourName.getSelectedItems.toString.toUpperCase().contains("T"))
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @Tom Probably why it does not compile, as it will not compile like that. :-)

Comment: [Retrieving Text from TextField](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31260653/452708)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (tfYourName.getText().toUpperCase().contains("T"))
    counter++;
```

Comment: "//more code here" should be probably `counter++;` :)

Comment: Yeah, just didn't know what counter was- I can change it